# Cannot access Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

I am trying to access GEE through colab as I always do. Now access has been denied. I get this error message

I get error of permission denied reason being

> USER_PROJECT_DENIED

following the link given I should submit the following to project administrator

```
Troubleshooting info:
  Principal: tshepho82@gmail.com
  Resource: 522309567947
  
Missing permissions:
  resourcemanager.projects.get
  resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy
```

Has anyone experienced this and how did you fix it?

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/cloud/earthengine_cloud_project_setup)?